# Morphological skeleton looking strange

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I've implemented morphological skeletonization to get the skeleton of digits from pictures.
There are 8 structuring elements to be compared to the neighborhood of a pixel. If some condition equals true, the foreground pixel is deleted. This is repeated until no more pixels are deleted, the output is the skeleton of the input.

The output of my implementations seems ok, but doesn't look as nice as the output of the Matlab function bwmorph.
There are some little lines on my output, which I would like to be removed.
Look at the two pictures I've linked to this post. The Matlab version looks "clearer" to me than my version.

I've heard of "pruning" to get rid of those little lines. But those algorithms look pretty complex. Is there a simple solution to get rid of those lines? Or is there some Matlab built-in function to remove those lines?

Pictures:

My own implementation: [image]

Matlab: [image]

Comment: why aren't you using `bwmorph`?

Comment: we have to implement our own versions (to get a deeper understanding) for an image processing course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, MatLab certainly uses a pruning after computing the skeleton. But pruning algorithm (at least most of them) work exactly as skeleton algorithm: a simple mask to apply.

Comment: I solved the problem by a simple "pruning" algorithm. As you mentioned, it works pretty the same as the skeleton algorithm. The difference is that you have to specify how many iterations should be executed. If you do not limit those iterations, everything disappears and you just get a black image ;-) But in my case 3 iterations did the job very well. Pruning: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm

Comment: I guess MatLab makes a little statistical study on the branches length, and choses the number of iteration accordingly.